# Function in another function parameters

Tags: c++

Well, basically i have browse through all the q&a about this and cant find my answer.

This is my code where it will do the calculation for square, cube, fourth of a number. But, there's an error when trying to output the answer.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int square (int);  //n^2
int cube (int);  //n^3
int fourth (int);  //n^4
void powerN(int x[], const int sizex, void(*select)(int))
{
    cout<< x[sizex];
    cout<<" to the power of "<<sizex+2<<" is ";
    cout<<(*select)(x[sizex])<<endl;
}
int square (int a)
{
    return a*a;
}
int cube (int b)
{
    return b*b*b;
}
int fourth (int c)
{
    return c*c*c*c;
}
int main()
{
    int a[3]={3,4,5};
    for (int aSize=0;aSize<3;a++){
    powerN (a, aSize, square);
    powerN (a, aSize, cube);
    powerN (a, aSize, fourth);
    }
}
```

Comment: _But, there's an error when trying to output the answer._ And the error is? Is it a secret?

Comment: Ditto, error messages exist for a reason: to help you figure out what caused the error! Always, always, _always_ include any error messages in your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The function pointer parameter `select`'s type is incorrect. You declare its return type as `void`, which can't be `cout`ed. The return value should be of type `int`.

   ```
   void powerN(int x[], const int sizex, int(*select)(int))
   //                                    ~~~
   ```
2. The for loop in `main()`, `a++` should be `aSize++`.

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/REV37328)